# ActivityScenario.launch not returning control flow / hanging

Tags: android, android-testing, robolectric, koin

I have an issue where ActivityScenario.launch is not returning control flow, but hanging. This create an issue where the test cases are not run and the test just sits indefinitely.

I am using koin, robolectric, jetpack components, and `LiveData`

The code is below. The Activity never reaches `onPause` or appears to crash.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(instrumentedPackages = ["androidx.loader.content"], application = Application::class)
class MainActivityTest {

@get:Rule
var rule: TestRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

@get:Rule
val coroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()

private val viewModel: MainActivityViewModel = mockk(relaxed = true)
private val homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = mockk<HomeViewModel>(relaxed = true).apply {
    every { homeState } returns MutableStateFlow(HomeState(UiState.Loading))
}
val module = module {
    viewModel { viewModel }
    viewModel { homeViewModel }
}

private lateinit var activityScenarioRule: ActivityScenario<MainActivity>

@Before
fun setUp() {
    startKoin {
        androidContext(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Application>())
        modules(testAppModules + module)
    }

    activityScenarioRule = ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)
}

@Test
fun onNewIntent() {
    activityScenarioRule.result
    activityScenarioRule.onActivity {
        assertThat(it).isNotNull()
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem did you had a look at this github issue?
https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/676#issuecomment-658135299
there seems to be a bug with retrieving the activities result, considered workaround at the moment is copied from the linked discussion:

```
// define our custom result property
val ActivityScenario<*>.safeResult: Instrumentation.ActivityResult
    get() {
        awaitBlock { state == Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED } // await for the activity to be destroyed
        return this.result // this will return quick as the result is already retrieved
    }


// util function to retry and await until the block is true or the timeout is reached
fun awaitBlock(timeOut: Int = 7500, block: () -> Boolean) {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    var value = block.invoke()
    while (!value && System.currentTimeMillis() < start + timeOut) {
        wait(50)
        value = block.invoke()
    }
    Assert.assertTrue("Couldn't await the condition", value)
}
```

The only other cause i could find so far might be using launchMode=singleInstance, when running with launchMode=singleTask it might succeed there it might be a work around to programmatically replace it accordingly
https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/1115#issuecomment-1196503160

Comment: I didn't try that, but I seemed to have found a way around it but don't remember what - will look to see if I can find what I came up with